# How to get an object from the arrayList after 30 days of created

Tags: java

I have a array list with a bunch of objects, and I set a date field for each object so it can be recognize on what date that object was created. I want to display that object 30 days after it was created.

I tried:

```
Object o2 = new Object("Mark", 23, "12/24/2015");
    System.out.println(o2);               //supposing that this is my object 



SimpleDateFormat formatDate = new SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd/yyyy");
    // and this is a Simple format date.

    try {
        Date objDate = formatDate.parse(o2.getDate()); 
        System.out.println(objDate);    //And here i take form a string date into a date.

    } catch (ParseException ex) {
        System.out.println(ex.getMessage());
    }
```

But I don't know how display the object 30 days after it was created.

Comment: Can you give the definition of Date Object you have referred to?

Comment: Is the date for an object.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should not use arraylist to implement this demand. However PriorityQueue does. You can use PriorityQueue to store your object, your object need implement a Comparator which compare by their createdTime.

```
public class MyObject {
    private String name;
    private int id;
    private long time;

}

public static Comparator<MyObject> COMPARE = new Comparator<MyObject>() {
    @Override
    public int compare(MyObject o1, MyObject o2) {
        return (int) (o1.time - o2.time);
    }
};

public PriorityQueue<MyObject> queue = new PriorityQueue<>(COMPARE);
```

then create a task to poll object from queue, display the object if created 30 days, or else add to queue again.

```
private class MyTask implements Runnable {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        while (true) {
            MyObject object = queue.poll();
            if (object.time + DateUtils.MILLIS_PER_DAY * 30 > System.currentTimeMillis()) {
                display(object);
            } else {
                queue.add(object);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

You also can use redis's zadd and zrangeByScoreWithScores to get data with socre computed by time. So that, do not need to poll and add multi times.

Answer (score 0):

You have two possibilities:

- Create a timer starting each day that loops through your list and check if an element is older than 30 days
- Start a new timer after each insertion with a delay of 30 days with an action that show your element

Here is an example on how to do that:

```
public class MyTask extends TimerTask {
    private Object o;

    public MyTask(Object o) {
        this.o = o;
    }

    public void run() {
        System.out.println(o);
    }
}

// in your code where you add an object to the list

Timer timer = new Timer();
myList.add(myObject);   // myObject is the object you add to the list
MyTask myTask = new MyTask(myObject);
//  1000 * 60 * 60 * 24 * 30 is equivalent to 30 days
timer.schedule(myTask , 1000 * 60 * 60 * 24 * 30);
```

Comment: Can you help me telling me how is it? i'm new in java.

Comment: I added an example for the second option

Comment: Millisecons seconds minute hours days

Comment: Sorry    it is myTask

Comment: I'm not clear how to implements your answer into an arraylist! @Davide

Comment: MyList can be an ArrayList

Answer (score 0):

You will need to create a class which contains the data and the "Date" (java.util.Date) on which the object was created. You can store this in an "ArrayList" You could then use a Timer class with a fixed interval of 1 day to check if the content is more than 30 days old.